# SSIS Data Flow Task: Is there a way to arrow multiple processes back to one?

Tags: ssis

I have a Data Flow task with a Lookup on two columns (id, SystemModstamp) that has three branches:

- Match Not Found - Insert.  Works fine when it was just this.

... and if a match is found I've just added a Conditional split to test variable overwrite_matches...

- If overwrite_matches='Y', delete the matching rows (TF Delete Batch
  in below image), then insert.
- If overwrite_matches='N', get a row count called 'no action' and do
  nothing.

**Question:** How can I pull off the blue-green arrow in the below image, set a precedence constraint (I know, they don't exist in data flow tasks) between the #2 TF Delete Batch transform, and the Derived Column, so that the Derived Column does not execute until both have been completed?

All that's coming to mind is a Union All / Merge / Merge Join, but I don't want the stream in the #2 TF delete to impact the downstream INSERT, as that's already in the #1 stream.
[image]

Comment: You can do a Merge Join, which will force the Derived Column to wait, and then just not use any of the JOINed columns in your final downstream INSERT, so it will have no impact.

Comment: Not a bad idea, testing it now, but that would mean that I would have to sort both columns.

Comment: Does the component that is "TF Delete Batch Transform" support an output stream?

Comment: No.  I just figured it out with a Homer Simpson 'Doh!' moment.  Because of the conditional split, the two streams have different rows in them (matched vs. unmatched), so there is no impact as to whether they execute concurrently or not.  Changed the TF Delete to a TF Insert, and good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I just figured it out with a Homer Simpson 'Doh!' moment. Because of the Lookup, the two streams have different rows in them (matched vs. unmatched), so there is no impact as to whether they execute concurrently or not. Changed the TF Delete to a TF Insert, and good to go.

Sorry for the inconvenience guys.